# How to manage/manipulate from a Java Application (IBM Connections) the uploaded Files

Tags: java, websphere-portal, ibm-connections

Do you know a way to manipulate the files stored in IBM Connections from a **Java** application deployed in Websphere Portal 8.5.

I want to be able to read those files without having to download them.

I read about the Rest API (Files API), but this requires to download the file. [Files API Here](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%205.0%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Files_API_ic50&content=apicontent)

I've also heard about IBM Social Business Toolkit (IBM SBT). But this SDK also makes me download the file (It is just a wrapper of the same Rest API).

I want to install an application inside the same **Websphere Portal** and manage the files locally (The files are physically stored on the same server).

Comment: If your customer uses any Compliance APIs, this approach would circumnavigate the compliance apis.  Also Connections has an internal messaging bus for events, you'd potentially be changing the file (which normally would cause an event).  You should use the Files API and disable notifications as a parameter on the API request.  Yes it delays processing, it's just the cleanest approach.